# Launch Iceweasel (Firefox) window undecorated

Tags: debian, openbox

I am on Debian, where firefox is called Iceweasel. I would like it to start undecorated. I have added the following to my `.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`, but it has no effect:

```
<application name="firefox-bin">
  <focus>yes</focus>
  <decor>no</decor>
  <maximized>true</maximized>
</application>
```

I have also tried different names, such as `firefox`, `iceweasel`, `iceweasel-bin`, but to no avail. Only when I add

```
<application name="*">
```

does `iceweasel` start undecorated (as do all other applications, obviously)

**NOTE:** I have the same problem with `Icedove` (Thunderbird)

**UPDATE**: as suggested by goldilocks, following is the output of `ps -A | less`

```
....
 9501 ?        00:18:40 iceweasel
14826 ?        00:00:21 icedove
....
```

Comment: Try `ps -A | less` while it's running and have a look through the list for the correct executable name.

Comment: please see my update

Comment: Ah, I think an issue here is the browser changes its name (WRT to the X server) to what you see in the title bar, which is the title of the loaded page.  If it has a prefix like "Iceweasel -- " and you can match against that (`Iceweasel*`) great, otherwise you need some other characteristic.  I notice there is a `WM_WINDOW_ROLE(STRING) = "browser"` in the `xprop` output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[You can use `xprop`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows#Launching_Windows_Maximized) to find a suitable way to refer to windows.
Open a terminal and the window of interest so that both are visible.
In the terminal, run

```
xprop | grep "^_OB_APP"
```

Your mouse cursor changes appearance into `crosshairs`. Move the cursor over to the window of interest and click within that window. The cursor reverts to its regular appearance and output appears in the terminal window. For example, suppose you clicked on a Firefox browser window, you'd see:

```
_OB_APP_TYPE(UTF8_STRING) = "normal"
_OB_APP_TITLE(UTF8_STRING) = "Mozilla Firefox"
_OB_APP_GROUP_CLASS(UTF8_STRING) = "Firefox"
_OB_APP_GROUP_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "firefox"
_OB_APP_CLASS(UTF8_STRING) = "Firefox"
_OB_APP_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Navigator"
_OB_APP_ROLE(UTF8_STRING) = "browser"
```

You then use the appropriate string in your application rule.
(Note that you can use `xprop` to also identify dialog windows to ensure that rules do or don't apply to them.)

---

I use:

```
<application role="browser">
  <maximized>true</maximized>
  <decor>no</decor>
</application>
```

to have all browsers open maximized and without decoration.

The other precaution to take is that the code is located appropriately. In other words, these lines should be in the "applications" section of `rc.xml` and should be within `<applications>` and `</applications>` and above the final line which should contain just `</openbox_config>`.

---

The other important thing is to run `openbox --reconfigure` to get the changes to be effected immediately. Running `openbox --reconfigure` also does a scan for `xml` errors and so is worth running after any edits to `rc.xml`.

Comment: +1 But my output doesn't include anything starting `_OB` -- the title is in `WM_NAME(STRING)`.

Comment: Is Openbox your window manager?

Comment: No, Kwin.  I guess that's the 'OB'. :)

Comment: All works perfectly now. Thanks a lot. I had to use `<application name="Navigator">` for firefox and `<application name="Mail">` for Thunderbird